# Is kinetic friction opposite to the velocity even in circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Is kinetic friction opposite to the velocity even in circular motion?[image]

Comment: Yes. What else is your question?

Comment: The friction force is in opposite direction of the relative velocity between the two surfaces. It seeks to oppose the surfaces sliding over each other.

Comment: Does the kinetic friction affects the radial axis too ?

Comment: Do you mean the radius?

Comment: No its horizontally motion above a table and the radius of the motion is constant.  @FakeMod

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by "Does the kinetic friction affect the radial axis too?"

Comment: @sammygerbil  im talking about polar coordinates: (r, θ)

Comment: What about the polar co-ordinates? Are you asking if friction will reduce the radius of the circle? No, you have already said the radius of the motion is constant. So what do you mean? What are you asking about the polar co-ordinates? Are you asking if kinetic friction provides the centripetal force which keeps the bead moving at a fixed distance from the axis?

Comment: @sammygerbil Its given that the radius is constant and the bead progress and the v0(velocity at t=0sec) .

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I don't understand what you are asking about the polar co-ordinates and friction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by *kinetic friction*, since there are several forces that may be referred by this term. If in this context it means *sliding frictiob*, i.e. what *sratic friction* force becomes when object begins to slide, then by its very definition it is directed against the direction of motion. This does not exclude the possibility that another component if the friction force still plays a role of static friction.

However, rotation provides many situation where friction enters the picture. An object placed in a disk and rotating with it, experiences a friction force that provides its normal acceleration. But this is to *static friction*. The disk itself experiences friction in its axis of rotation.

Comment: The black dot is a a bead moving on a hoop in horhorizontally movement . only the bead is progress

Comment: And what do you call *kinetic friction*? The *sliding friction*?

Comment: @Vadim In most physics textbooks and other contexts, kinetic friction is sliding friction. Another use of "kinetic friction" would be anomalous.

Comment: In my courses *kinetic friction* was reserved for *rolling resistance*, since *sliding friction* is not really kinetic in its nature. But I did my undergrad in a different language, so you are probably right.